# Can not set property to null

Tags: javascript

Ok this probably is stupid question but I've been sitting here trying to fix this issue.  I have a select list and when it changes to a specific value i'm trying to set a property to empty string and disable some other fields.  Problem is I keep getting the 'TypeError: Cannot set property 'msrp' of null error.  I've been looking at this for a while now.  Here is the code :

```
            var msrp;             
            vm.changeDealType = function changeDealType(myScenario, typeId) {

                scenario.isCashDealType = false;
                msrp = '';                          
                if( typeId.value !== null && typeId.value === "Cash"){
                    myScenario.isCashDealType = true;
                    myScenario.original.msrp = msrp;
                }

            };
```

Comment: That means that myScenario.original  or myScenario.original.msrp is null

Comment: Looks like when your `changeDealType` function is called `myScenario.original` is null.

Comment: What is `myScenario.original`? It looks like that's null (which would cause your code to squawk when setting a property on something null)

Comment: Logically, you don't have to check for both value !== null and value === "cash"
You check for only one of them. if value =="cash" and that's it

Comment: `myScenario.original.msrp = msrp; // <-- myScenario.original isn't defined here`  console.log myScenario at that point and paste here please?

Comment: @admcfajn 'TypeError: Cannot set property 'msrp'

Comment: @AmrElgarhy I was totally overlooking that had been sitting here just ugh nevermind thanks all that helped.

Comment: @TroyBryant to console.login a closure where an error is occurring, your may have to comment out the erroneous code; otherwise, the error might throw before the console.log can. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your codes, remember you need to send the proper input as required for your function for example:

```
var myScenario = {};
myScenario.original = {};
var typeId = {};
changeDealType(myScenario, typeId);
```

You may try with this working code without any errors:

```js
var msrp;

function changeDealType(myScenario, typeId) {

  myScenario.isCashDealType = false;
  msrp = '';
  if (typeId.value !== null && typeId.value === "Cash") {
    myScenario.isCashDealType = true;
    myScenario.original.msrp = msrp;
  }

};

var myScenario = {};
myScenario.original = {};
var typeId = {};
changeDealType(myScenario, typeId);
```